# filter input string to array python

Tags: python, arrays, string, filter

I am trying to make an array out of the following string:

`'25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n'`

Where only the numbers need to be added.

I have tried the following:

```
MyString.decode().strip('\r\n')
```

But then i just removed the '\r\n'

**Question: Is there a way to filter on only the numbers and put it in an array?**

EDIT:

```
array = [int(x) for x in data.split('\r\n')]
```

this seems to work, only not in my case.

I am working with bluetooth and so I am trying to read the outputstream.

here is my code:

```
    def bluetooth_connect(self):
    bd_addr = "98:D3:31:FB:14:C8"   # MAC-address of our bluetooth-module
    port = 1
    sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))

    data = ""
    while 1:
        try:
            data += sock.recv(1024)
            data_end = data.find('\n')
            array = []

            if data_end != -1:
                self.move_all_servos(data)
                data = data[data_end + 1:]
                array = [int(x) for x in data.split('\r\n')]

                for i in range(0, leng(array)):
                     print(i)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
    sock.close()
```

first i get the correct array, but after a while it crashes with this error:

`array = [int(x) for x in data.split('\r\n')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: `[int(x) for x in s.split('\r\n')]`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I think this will die on the empty string at the end of the split.

Comment: better `[int(x) for x in s.strip('\r\n').split('\r\n')]`

Comment: Just `[int(x) for x in s.split()]` is enough.

Comment: @tobias_k you're right. but why `s.split()` result doesn't contain empty string element, but `s.split('\r\n')` result contains? Sorry for question, I'm surprised, I'll read docs ))

Comment: s.split() works fine.

Comment: @arlanschouwstra: NobbyNobbs already gave you the correct solution: you have to strip the last `\r\n`.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs I'm as surprised as you, but actually it's in the docs. from `help(str.split)`: "If sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator and _empty strings are removed from the result_."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `[int(x) for x in data.split('\r\n')]` is that the result will contain an empty string `''` at the end, after the final `\r\n`. You could use a filter condition to remove it...

```
>>> [int(x) for x in data.split('\r\n') if x]
[25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25]
```

... or just use `data.split()` without parameter:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in data.split()]
[25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25, 35, 5, 15, 25]
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> ```
> S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings
> ```
>
> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
>   delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>   splits are done. **If sep is not specified** or is None, any
>   whitespace string is a separator and **empty strings are
>   removed from the result**.

Answer (score 0):

Use split.

```
s = '25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n35\r\n5\r\n15\r\n25\r\n'
s.split('\r\n')
```

Comment: better call in comments

Comment: As it stands, this splits the string into a list, and then... well, the list is garbage-collected.